# Placing text in the margin next to a figure using ConTeXt

Tags: floats, positioning, context

What is a good way to place a short paragraph in the margin next to a figure in ConTeXt?

I've been trying the following code, but it places the `\inmargin` text at the base of the figure which only works for about 2 lines before the text goes well beneath the end of the figure.

```
\starttext
\starthanging
{\placefigure[force][fig:figure-reference]{Figure Caption}
{\externalfigure[figure-file][width=\textwidth]}}
\inmargin{Sometext that is intended for the Margin}
\stophanging
\stoptext
```

[image]

I've had a quick look in the Details Manual but was unable to find or work out what to apply to get a good result.

Comment: I have completed your code snippet into a MWE and added the output. I hope that is OK. `:-)`

Comment: That is most definitely OK. Thank you very much. This demonstrates the issue clearly.

Comment: You use a too old version. It was fixed before 2012-12-06. What version are you running?

Comment: It was an old version problem. Thanks Marco!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which is fixed in the current release version.